# How to install ssl certificate received from SSLForFree.com on IIS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I received an SSL certificate from [sslforfree.com](https://www.sslforfree.com/). It is a .zip file consisting of 3 files:

1. certificate.crt
2. private.key
3. ca_bundle.crt

How should I install this certificate on IIS 8.0? (What am I supposed to do with these 3 files?)

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: The first file is the certificate public key. 

The second file is the certificate private key.

The last file contains combined root and intermediate certificates.

Comment: Surely you have misunderstood? A private key sourced from elsewhere isn't private, by definition, so cannot fulfil the purpose for which it was created. If this is really true you should just throw it away and try a better provider.

Answer (score 10):

**First**, you need to make a .pfx file to make things easy. You need to Install [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) and run the following in a command prompt with path set to location of downloaded certificate files

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out "certificate_combined.pfx" -inkey "private.key" -in "certificate.crt" -certfile ca_bundle.crt`

**Second**, import the certificate to IIS:

[image]

[image]
*Note: You created the password when you created .pfx file with openssl in command prompt.*

**Third**, bind https to the website and choose the imported certificate in "Add Site Binding" window:

[image]
*Note: You need to do this **once for every domain name**. For example if you have "www.abc.com" and also "abc.com" as your domain names you must do the https binding two times and each time write the corresponding domain name in "Add Site Binding" window and make sure that "Require Server Name Indication" is checked. Also you need to add another extra https binding **without** checking "Require Server Name Indication" and **without** writing any Host name to remove the "No default SSL site has been created" warning in IIS.*

**Congragulations**. You are done. Now your website can be accessed with securely with https without any warning or error.

Comment: I downloaded the tar.gz file from Openssl and extracted the files into a folder with Winzip. but I cant seem to install it. When I try the CMD command it says that: Openssl command is not recognized. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: There seems to have been an .exe offered by Open SSL but now they are only providing the source in tar format